# How to use defeated/scored/won?

Tags: vocabulary

I know their meanings, but when it comes to application, I can't differentiate their use since they're slightly have the same meaning. (perhaps?)

Here is an example I took from online try out test I took a few days ago:

> Team A ___ team B 5-2 in last night's football match to go into the
> final next week.
>
> A) defeated
>
> B) scored
>
> C) won

I'm confused to tell the difference in its use this time. Is it B)? It's just my guess, I chose B) becuase it sounded more appropriate, but hope you will tell the difference. As always, thank you in advance!

Comment: **Team A** is the subject. **Team B** is the object. **Five-to-two** (5–2) is an adverbial phrase modifying your chosen verb. Knowing this, look again at the definitions of **defeat**, **score**, and **win**. Does one choice make more sense than the others? (Hint: Look at whether each verb is *transitive* or *intransitive*.)

Comment: @randomhead about the hint, I don't thinks it helped me. Becuase, I've looked-up the definitions and they are all can be transitive. Sorry. I still didn't get that.

Comment: Yes, they can all be transitive. randomhea's point is that a good dictionary will make clear what kind of subject and object each should have. Only one of those words fits with "team A" as the subject and "team B" as the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the definitions for each verb.

> [**defeat**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defeat#Etymology_1), Etymology 1
>
> 1. (*transitive*) To overcome in battle or contest.

This is a viable choice.
One team *defeated* the other team.

---

> [**score**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/score#English)
> 3. (*transitive, intransitive)* To obtain something desired.
> 3.1. To earn points in a game.

This does not make sense in context.
*Points* or *goals* are "scored."
A team is not "scored" (though it does, itself, score [points or goals]).
Unless the object is a point or goal (or similar), *score* is an intransitive verb.

---

> [**win**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/win#English), Etymology 1
> 6. (*intransitive*) To achieve victory.

Again, this is an intransitive verb and cannot fit in this context.

*Win* is a tricky one because there are many definitions.
You may see

> 3. (*transitive*) To triumph or achieve victory in (a game, a war, etc.).

or

> 8. (*transitive*) To obtain (something desired).

and think that those would fit here.
They do not: Remember that the object is "Team B."
Looking at these definitions, if Team A "won" Team B, that would mean they *acquired* Team B, perhaps as some sort of deal where the losing side would join forces with the winners and continue to play other teams as one super-team.
This is not the meaning contained in the sentence; all we want to say is that Team A *was victorious over* Team B.

---

So of the three choices, only "defeat" is correct in context.